# Android: How config emulator GUI to proxy my http traffic?

Tags: android-emulator

If I want to proxy all my http traffic to my proxy on local machine I use this (in command line)

```
emulator -avd Nexus_6_0_emulator -http-proxy 172.17.102.35:8080
```

It's work. As result all my http traffic from emulator go throw my proxy (172.17.102.35:8080) to production server. OK!

But I need to set proxy by emulator GUI.

I try this:

- **Settings->More->Cellular network->Access point names** and edit the EXISTING Access Point.

[image]

- Restart emulator

but it's not help.